# How to avoid overfitting with genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am facing the following problem.
I have a system able to produce a ranking of some operations according to their anomaly score. To improve the performance I implemented a genetic algorithm to perform a features selection, such that the most anomalous operations appears in the first positions. What I am doing is not exactly feature selection, because I am not using binary variables, rather float variables between 0-1, which sum is equal to 1.

Currently, I have a population of 200 individuals for 50 generations. I am using as the evaluation function the system itself and I evaluate the quality of the solution by using the true positive rate, counting how many anomalous operations appears in the first N positions (where N is the number of anomalous operations). Then as operator the uniform crossover and I change a valueof a cell of the individual for the mutation. Of course, every time I make a check to fix the individual such that the sum is 1. Finally I use elitism to save the best-so-far solution over the time.

I observed that one feature has a very high value, which is often important, but not always, and this causes very low values for the other features. I suspect that my GA is overfitting.
Can you help me to find a good stop criteria?

Comment: Could you provide some code by any chance?

Comment: Sorry, I can not. Anyway if you need of more details, tell me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Overfitting in genetic algorithms and programming is a big issue which is currently under research focus of the GP community, including myself. Most of the research is aimed at genetic programming and evolution of classification/regression models but it might also relate to your problem. There are some papers which might help you (and which I am working with too):

- Gonçalves, Ivo, and Sara Silva. "Experiments on controlling overfitting in genetic programming." Proceedings of the 15th Portuguese Conference on Artificial Intelligence: Progress in Artificial Intelligence, EPIA. Vol. 84. 2011.
- Langdon, W. B. "Minimising testing in genetic programming." RN 11.10 (2011): 1.
- Gonçalves, Ivo, et al. "Random sampling technique for overfitting control in genetic programming." Genetic Programming. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012. 218-229.
- Gonçalves, Ivo, and Sara Silva. Balancing learning and overfitting in genetic programming with interleaved sampling of training data. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2013.

You can find the papers (the first two directly in pdf) by searching for their titles in scholar.google.com.

Basically, what all the papers work with, is the idea of using only a subset of the training data for directing the evolution and (randomly) changing this subset every generation (using the same subset for all individuals in one generation). Interestingly, experiments show that the smaller this subset is, the less overfitting occurs, up to the extreme of using only a single-element subset. The papers work with this idea and extend it with some tweaks (like switching between full dataset and a subset). But as I said in the beginning, all this is aimed at symbolic regression (more or less) and not feature selection.

I personally once tried another approach (again for symbolic regression by genetic programming) - using a subset of training data (e.g. a half) to drive the evolution (i.e. for fitness), but the "best-so-far" solution was determined using results on the remaining training data. The overfitting was much less significant.

Comment: First of all thank you for the references in your reply, very helpful. Can you give me in short some hint that I can understand better and deeper after reading the papers you cited? I would like reading those papers having already an idea of the used techniques.

Comment: With due respect, user2297037, Honza did help you a lot in directing your attention in spite of your refusal to be more specific about any tiny detail of your problem/approach. Having respected your decision not to tell any further detail about neither a kind of GP/EP algorithm, nor the fitness-function, nor any of the further details on constrained/unconstrained type of generation, **it seems rather unpolite & unfair to ask for additional help and advice the very people whom you have a-priori refused to tell more about your problem and your prior solution approach**

Comment: @user2297037 I extended my answer a little bit.

Comment: Pardon, I do not want to start a fight, but let me explain. I did not refuse to be more specific, actually I said feel free to ask me for more details. I could not post the exact code. To be honest I am happy to share with you the details, because I can receive a feedback from people more expert than me. I extend my question with other information, but tell me what you actually need to know. Maybe this misunderstanding is due to my bad english, so excuse me.
@Jan Žegklitz Thank you very much I appreciated a lot your explanation and the references that I am going to read immediately.

Comment: @zegkljan Thanks for the great answer! Have you further developed your approach described in the last section of your answer? Is there a publication by any chance about this?

Comment: @VSZM The author has further investigated the proposed method, and it has published in GECCO. You can search "Model selection and overfitting in genetic programming: empirical study" in Google to get that paper. In this paper, the author has conducted some experiments indicate that the sub-sampling method may not be a useful way to improve the testing performance.